# Want Count ListView Items and show counter on every ListView Items

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

I got stuck in Counting `ListView` items and show Counters on Particular ListView Items . Pleas see below for actually what I want to do:

Here's a sample of ListView Items:

Syllabus **(List Items Counting)**             < My Heading >

Ex.

- Syllabus (1/10)             Android
- Syllabus (2/10)             Java
- Syllabus (10/10)            Java
- ...more

I am getting these list view items from My Local Database, Please suggest me any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to you create subclass of some `ListAdapter` and in `getView()` method just use **int position** for getting position of each child and **size of datasource** for getting total count.

For example if you'll use `SimpleCursorAdapter` so use `cursor.getCount()` for count of items and `int position` parameter of `getView()` method for getting position of each child(row).

Basic example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   if (c.moveToPosition(position) { 
      String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.COL));
      String another = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.COL_2));
      String text = value + "(" + String.valueOf(position) + "/" + String.valueOf(c.getCount()) + ") " + another; 
      textView.setText(text);
   }
}
```

Comment: I hv done below code from your Explanation and your sample code..
mHolder.mTxt_index.setText((position + 1) + "/" + MyFragment.<ArrayList>.size());

Thanx a lot sajmon_d.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a text view in the custom layout for the list and set `position +"/10"` in that text view.

Comment: I have no. of items not only 10. by d way Thanx.. AnujMathur.

Comment: So u can change "/10" by what ever you want, like by the size of array or arraylist you are using for generating list.

Comment: Thanx for yr suggestion AnujMathur... :) I hv solved my problem this way: mHolder.mTxt_index.setText((position + 1) + "/" + MyFragment.<ArrayList>.size());

Answer (score 0):

you can get length of total item and then try with below code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
 Syllabus (i/total length) < My Heading >
       }
```

Comment: Thanx for yr suggestion kyogs... :) I hv solved my problem this way: mHolder.mTxt_index.setText((position + 1) + "/" + MyFragment.<ArrayList>.size()); But from your code I solved many prob.s :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your custom CursorAdapter, like

```
public class ExampleCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public ExampleCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView summary = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.summary);
    summary.setText(cursor.getString(
            cursor.getColumnIndex(ExampleDB.KEY_EXAMPLE_SUMMARY)));
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    bindView(v, context, cursor);
    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanx for yr suggestion Kapil Vats... But I hv solved my problem this way:
 mHolder.mTxt_index.setText((position + 1) + "/" + MyFragment.<ArrayList>.size());